# I want to update Opportunity owner field value

Tags: opportunity, lookup, user, object

I want to update Opportunity owner field value to same as an other user lookup field on opportunity object whenever this lookup field is updated. can i do this using workflow or trigger would be better option?

Answer (score 0):

You can use workflow field update or by using Process builder (if no other triggers are already available).

If you already have a trigger then put the logic in trigger.

Basically, you need to design based on your purpose and optimized way.

Comment: Thank you Santanu for the suggestion... since workflow field update cant change value dynamically. I guess Process Builder or Trigger can be used